# Is there any way to create a new flutter project without vpn?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, vpn

Unable to make new flutter project in android studio . When I try to create a new Flutter app via Android Studio it never ends. I got "Creating Flutter Project" and that's it (No response).SDK location outside Program Files, Path set in variables, Flutter doctor found no issues, AS opened with admin rights.I tried to create Flutter through Command.And finally I used a vpn, it worked.But I can use it only 7 days free trial. So how can I create a new flutter project without vpn?

Answer (score 1):

In Iran, we use [freedom of developers](https://github.com/freedomofdevelopers/fod) or DNS changing services like [Shecan](https://shecan.ir/) to bypass restrictions.